# Pictures in announcements' body not showing up for some users?

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

We have a couple of announcements on the Intranet with pictures inserted into the body of the announcements.

While it whows up on most of our machines it fails to render on some of the other machines.

Please correct me if I am wrong here, but I am assuming this is not a sharepoint issue, rather an IE secutiry issue.

Please advise.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, it can also be a problem with permissions on the image/picture library from which the image is called. These are the following things you need to check

1. Permissions applied on the image and its checked out status.
2. Permissions of the picture library with respect to the users facing the problem.
3. Incase the image is located outside SharePoint, the actual url of the image location should be accessible from the user's system.

Incase its an IE issue, check for the security settings in IE in the affected user's browser and look for things that are blocked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had copied and pasted text and images from the test environment to the live. The pictures (on right click -> properties) were pointing to the test environment. Once I recreated them they worked just fine!